# Ramanujacharya's Brother

Tags: history, sri-vaishnava, ramanujacharya

'Who is Ramanujacharya's brother? He adopted Saivism when he was around 20 years old. How did Ramanuja brought back him to vaishnavism?Any mythological references for this.

Comment: Assuming what u are saying is true-What was the need for Ramanuja to bring back his bro "back to vaishnavism"?Does it imply that anyone born in a vaisnava family does not have rights to choose any deity other than Vishnu as his Ishta??That's extremism at its best imo.

Comment: When one is is a vaishnavite he will follow that only. We do that not like your nway of thinking. Even the sankalpa  varies. The symbol varies. Nowadays Brahmins are a rejected lot. What you people give answer is not deep tooted knowledge. For the time being to answer the question you refer some smiritis puranas and copy paste which is just an answer. Go thru deep imbibe analyse and reply. The you see the difference.

Comment: Everyone knows that the tilaka varies and the sankalpa varies ,,this is no deep knowledge..instead of parameswara prityartham one says narayana prithyartham...What i'm saying is Ishta devta is different from Kula devata.Forcing a devata upon someone is not hinduism its extremism..."You are bound to worship this God and no other.".this is called  fanaticism,extremism.

Comment: When we go for saranagathi baranyasa we will sorship only Lord Narasimha. No other God will be wsorshipped. Probably you are not aware of south indian cultures  this is an opportunity I have shared.

Comment: We follow certain rules if u do not want you will call fanacticism extremism etc.  we are least bothered about your comment.

Comment: I'm also not interested in knowing about a regional culture that promotes such extremism.And this is also not about a specific region or a specific culture.Its about Hinduism the Sanatana Dharma.I know that Sri Ramakrishna's Kula deity was Sri Rama but nobody objected when he became devoted to Mother Goddess.This is the way it should be.

Comment: If you are a kali baktha and me like vaishnavite ask you to come to Lord Krishna temple will you adhere?

Comment: Do u mean to say that in ur place devotees of Devi don't visit Vishnu temples and vice versa???!!! I'm really SHOCKED to hear this. Vishnu is our Kula Devata.I love him as much as i love my Ishta.I have done numerous ekadasi fasts..Not agreeing going to a Vishnu temple is out of question.i mean i don't really know why i'm discussing these things with u.:banghead:

Comment: How is this a 'mythology' question? What do you mean by 'mythological references' for a question such as yours?

Comment: @sv---For questions about stories that are part of Hindu religious beliefs. Hindu mythology can be found throughout Hindu scriptures like the Vedas, Puranas, Ramayana, and Mahabharata  this is the description in the site itself--Pl go through before asking question

Comment: @Rickross--We as a vaishnavite rely fully on narayana   [maha Vishnu] and Lakshmi. We will not step in to other temples. We see all the deities in narayana and Lakshmi. No need to step in other temples.  If u bang head swelling will come. U will faint.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan I don't think this is a 'mythology' question, we use that tag for any questions based on stories or characters in Puranas, Ramayana, and Mahabharata. The 'history' tag is probably more relevant here.

Comment: @sv.--I agree with your comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

emBAr is the cousin(Ramanuja mother’s younger sister’s son) of Sri Ramanuja.

Swami EmBaar was born  in Madhuramangalam (then known as Mazhalai
 mangalam) to pious couple Periya Pratti and Sri Kamalanayana Bhatta in
 the year 1026 CE (Krodana samvatsaram) month of Makara ( Tamil Month
 of Thai ) under the the constellation of Punarvasu.  It is said he was
 the amsam of Vainatheyan . His maternal uncle Thirumalai nambhi named
 him as Govinda Bhatta.

> Later, while taking bath in Ganges with Yadavaprakasar and ashram
>    mates, Sri Govinda Battar gets a lingam in his hand. Sri Govinda
>    Bhattar shows the same to his guru. The advaitic scholar replied that
>    it is the anugruham of Lord Siva and names him as  **ULangai konNarnda
>    NAyanAr.** From that day, Govinda Bhattar becomes a pure advaitin and
>    starts practising the same.
>
> Then Govinda returned back and did the Prathistai of the Lingam in
>    Madhuramangalam ( even to this day you can see this Lingam) then he has seen a dream in which Lord of Kalahasthi beckoned him so he went to Kalahasthi and
>    continued to worship. Years rolled on Ramanujar also grew up and he
>    became the disciple of Thirukachi Nambhigal ,Periya
>    Nambhi,Thirukoshtiyur nambhi etc and he had become an ascetic . Sri
>    Ramanujar felt that he needed some trusted lieutenant to assist him ,
>    he then remembered Govinda , whose timely advice saved his life. 
>    Then he requested his Maternal uncle Thirumalai Nambhi to bring back
>    Govinda to Srivaishnava fold. Thirumalai Nambhi too had been thinking
>    of correcting Govinda Bhattar and hence immedietely left to Kalahasti
>    with few of his disciples and started giving discourses. He crossed
>    ULangai konNarnda NAyanAr’s path and makes [AaLavandAr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamunacharya)’s shlokam from [Stotra ratna](http://www.bvml.org/VS/Y_stotra-ratna.html) fall on his ears:
>
> **svAbhAvikAnavadhikAtisayEsitritvam
>
>   nArayANa tvayi na mrishyati vaidhikAh kah
>
>   brahma sivah satamakhah parama-svarad ity
>
>   ete 'pi yasya mahimArNava-viprushas te.**
>
> Meaning: O Lord Narayana, what learned Vedic scholar will not accept You as the all-powerful and unlimited Personality of Godhead? Brahma, Siva, Indra, and the liberated residents of Vaikuntha are but drops in the ocean of Your transcendental glory.
>
> Something in NAyanAr’s mind gets stirred when he hears the words and becomes
>    disturbed. On another occasion, Nambigal went and sits under the tree
>    from which NAyanAr used to pluck flowers everyday and starts teaching
>    the meaning of TiruvAimozhi to his disciples. NAyanar forgets his task
>    of gathering the flowers and stands there mesmerized. When Nambigal
>    was explaining the meaning of the pathu titled “Thinnan veedu” – there is a pasuram –
>
> **dhevum epporulum padaikkap poovil naanmukhanaip
>
>     padiaatha – devan Emperumaanukkallal Poovum poosanaiyum thagume ?**
>
> **Meaning: Would it even be appropriate to make flower offerings and other worship to any deity other than our NarAyaNan who created the four-faced BrahmA in His navel and entrusted him, under His direct control, with the
>   function of creating all the other deities and the other different
>   entities?**
>
> On hearing those words, NAyanAr throws the basket and the flowers and
>    cried by saying ‘thagathu ! thagathu !’ (It wouldn't, it wouldn't). Realising the folly he had been committing, he fell down at the feet of Thirumalai Nambi with tears rolling down his cheeks and cried for saving him and to change him to a Vaishnavate again.

Then Govinda went along with his uncle to Thirumalai to learn
 Divyaprabhandam etc. under him. He did kainkaryams to Sri Tirumalai
 Nambigal.

**Sources**

http://anudinam.org/2013/01/26/thirunakshatram-of-swami-embar/
https://guruparamparai.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/embar/

Comment: thagathu!thagathu! ( wrong wrong)
seems to better translation.
or (thangathu thangathu) (Cannot cannot)
It is a just a observation on a composed reply.