# Why did SriSailapurna say Sri Ramanuja's brother that Lord Shiva is 'Lila-dveshi'?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, terminology, ramanujacharya

I read in a biography of Sri Ramanujacharya that SriSailapurna asked Sri Ramanuja's brother Govinda, who was a devotee of Lord Shiva, to discard Shiva and worship Narayana instead, as Lord Shiva is 'Lila-dveshi'.

Lila means Divine play. Lord Shiva has many divine plays as mentioned in the different puranas. What is the connotation of the word 'lila-dveshi' as per the scriptures?

Comment: Can you tell which biography contains this?

Comment: It is not Ramanujarya who called Embar back. It was Ramanujacharya's uncle Tirumalai Nambi. [Can Sri Krishna be called 'a person'?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15616/5212) .The conversation which took place is a double entendre. It has one meaning outside and one inside.

Comment: That was a wrong link posted. Look at this question [Ramanujacharya's Brother](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15616/5212).

Comment: Your question says Ramanujacharya talked to Embar whereas it's his uncle Tirumalai Nambi. That is why I shared the question. The pashuram has a different and esoteric meaning than what it looks and can't be simply understood. No, the thought that treating Shiva and Vishnu as different will lead to hell is only limited to some people. That is not a universal thought. There is heirarchy between deities. Pancharatra agamas are strictly monotheistic and Vishnu is superior. Following those agamas and worship according to them doesn't not lead to hell.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma If you know tyese, why dont you write an answer instead of commenting?!

Comment: Is your question difference of Shiva and Vishnu and leading to hell? Or is it about SrisailaPurana asking Embar to return back to Vaishnavism? I commented about a factual error present in the question and you brought another topic which I replied. I was not answering your question in the comments. I was correcting your question and replying to you. You have to ask someone to write answers who writes comments as answer. btw, there is no hurry sir. You can type comment slowly ;-)

Comment: @Sarvabhuma Its not because of hurry but because of the small keypad:)My question is about why is Shiva branded as Liladveshi and that I think I have made clear in the question.BTW i dont know anyone who writes comments as answer.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma 'There is heirarchy between deities. Pancharatra agamas are strictly monotheistic and Vishnu is superior. Following those agamas and worship according to them doesn't not lead to hell.' – any scriptural injunction contradicting the Vedas is not acceptable and in the Vedas both Shiva and Vishnu are forms of the same Brahman. So people obeying any heirarchyvare at least neither illumined nor liberated.

Comment: @Pratimaputra Again it's limited interpretation that Shiva = Vishnu in Vedas. This is not contradicting the Vedas at all. Hinduism itself is monothesitic. Ekam eva advitiyam Brahma says the Upanishad and *ekam sat* viprah says Rigveda. So, Pancharatra agamas also say the same. Agamas are god's words not written by person. They are essence of Vedas. The rule that something should be discarded doesn't apply here at all. God's words are greater than anything. Vedas do not preach anything against God. Do they? Many liberated following agamas. So, they are right.